# Passing member variables (QList) by reference to a member function?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application whose purpose is to take a key press value and place it into a QList. However, every time I call the class member function that handles the QList modifications, the member variable `QList` gets reset. I believe I have a scope issue, but I can't figure out where. Here's my code:

**myClass.h**

```
class myClass
{

private:
  int var1;
  QList<int> list1;
  QList<int> list2;

public:
  myClass();
  //~MyClass();      //do I even need this?
  bool add(int i);
};
```

**myClass.cpp**

```
myClass::myClass()
{
  var1 = 50;
  QList<int> list1;
  QList<int> list2 ({0,10,20,30,40,50});
}

bool myClass::add(int i){
  qDebug() << "list1 before:";
  list1.append(i);
  qDebug() << "list1 after:";
  qDebug() << list1;
  qDebug() << "number of elements in list1:";
  qDebug() << list1.count();
  qDebug() << "print all list2 elements";
  qDebug() << list2;
  qDebug() << "var1 value:";
  qDebug() << var1;

  if (list1.count() < 2){
    return false;
  } else {
  return true;
  }
}
```

**myApp.cpp**

```
<....snip....>
void myApp::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{
  myClass keystroke;
  if (!keystroke.add(e->key())){
    qDebug() << "FALSE!!!";
  } else {
    qDebug() << "TRUE!!!";
  }
<....snip....>
```

Basically, what is happening here is in `myApp.cpp`, I'm creating a new object of type `myClass` that listens for any keyboard events, then takes the numeric value of that key and passes it to the `myClass` member function `add`.

Once the value is in `myClass::add`, it is appended to a member variable `QList` that is initialized in the `myClass::myClass` constructor. I have a few `qDebug()` lines in there that print the following upon hitting the `a` key:

```
list1 before:
()
list1 after:
(65)
number of elements in list1:
1
print all list2 elements
()
var1 value:
50
FALSE!!!
```

Here's the first issue. The key press value of `a` seems to come back fine and shows up as `(65)` when the elements of the `QList` that it's appended to (`list`) is printed. We can also see that the size of the `QList` is now `1`. Great. Since the size is not greater than 2, it returns false.

Ideally, when I hit another key (say, the `b` key), the key press value for `b` would be appended to the `QList`. So if I print the elements of `list1` again, it should come back with `(65, 66)`. But it doesn't. Here's what gets printed:

```
list1 before:
()
list1 after:
(66)
number of elements in list1:
1
print all list2 elements
()
var1 value:
50
FALSE!!!
```

It's like the `list1` `QList` resets itself and doesn't retain the first key press. Why is that? Am I not passing variables correctly?

I tested this further by initializing a constant `QList` named `list2`. I tried printing all of the elements of that `QList`, but as you can see above, it just comes back with `()`, meaning it's an empty list. I would think I should see it come back with `(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)`

This leads me to believe that I'm not passing variables correctly. I read up on passing variables by reference so that a copy of the variables are not made (which I think may be happening here), but how do I go about doing this correctly?

Also, another weird thing is that if I print the `var1` variable, it comes back with `50` just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but note that the declarations in your constructor are declarations of local variables. They do not initialize class members.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for the tip. Just to clarify: where should I be initializing the member variables if not in the constructor? I assumed best practice is to declare member variables in the header file, and then initialize them in the .cpp file's constructor.

Comment: No need to answer my above comment. @6502 answered it by noting that I should be using an initialization list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marked code

```
void myApp::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{
   myClass keystroke;  // <<=============== HERE
   if (!keystroke.add(e->key())){
```

means you're creating a new fresh instance of `myClass` at each keypress.

You should instead store the class instance as a member of the widget so it can remain alive between keystrokes.

Note also that, as it was told in the comments, your constructor

```
myClass::myClass()
{
  var1 = 50;
  QList<int> list1;
  QList<int> list2 ({0,10,20,30,40,50});
}
```

is not initializing the members, but simply declaring two local variables named `list1` and `list2`. To initialize the members the syntax is:

```
myClass::myClass()
  : var1(50), list2({0,10,20,30,40,50})
{
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and that did the job. For the record, I put the `myClass keystroke;` class instance in my widget's private member variable section. But would you happen to know why the elements of `list2` are not being printed correctly?

Comment: @orbit: see edit... that was covered by the comment from Alf

Comment: Thank you for the detail. This helps greatly.